# A heavily customized Spring Web application and the dispatcher servlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

We have a web application that uses spring, struts and camel right now and there is a lot of customization we have done to allow us to know when beans are added to the context.

So, we have gotten to a point where we would like to remove struts from the application, because we are only using it to handle actions and we figure we could either use spring or camel to do the same thing.  So I was able to get it to work with camel/velocity, but we didn't like how we really couldn't use the request object directly in the jsp (afaik, you have to put everything in the header of the Exchange and in the jsp you would do ${header.someReqVariableName}).

So we wanted to go the spring route, but since we load the context.xml directly, we have a provider that extends ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator and we pass the xml file name as a param, we haven't been able to figure out how to get the DispatcherServlet to work without giving it another configuration xml.

Is there a way to either:
Have camel use jsp for processing a jsp (and have all the usage of jsp tags)?
or
Have spring to see that a context has already been loaded and use that instead of having another new one?
or 
Something better I have thought up?

Comment: I guess a simpler question that may fit our need is is there a way to feed DispatcherServlet a already created BeanLocator?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [camel-jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) to expose HTTP endpoints, but I wouldn't use it for any complex web app development (JPS, etc).  I'd use use Spring MVC (or similar) and use Camel for any complex routing/messaging requirements...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, you can use the producer template to send the request to the camel context if you can get the reference of the camel context from the spring.